# ES module compiled with babel-cli is slower than babel-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I'm developing a express server with Javascript and I was using babel-node to compile it realtime.

Today I compiled it using babel-cli to run some benchmark tests and I realized it is about %50 slower than babel-node(I did them using https://github.com/wg/wrk).
I thought compiled codes would run faster. Am I doing something wrong?

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],

  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

babel-node result

```
kenny@kenny-Swift:~/Desktop/projects/wrk$ ./wrk  -c400 -d30s -t4 http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
Running 30s test @ http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
  4 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    84.13ms   18.85ms 217.29ms   86.26%
    Req/Sec     1.19k   239.36     1.61k    73.75%
  142627 requests in 30.04s, 35.91MB read
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 142627
Requests/sec:   4747.58
Transfer/sec:      1.20MB
```

babel-cli result

```
kenny@kenny-Swift:~/Desktop/projects/wrk$ ./wrk  -c400 -d30s -t4 http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
Running 30s test @ http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
  4 threads and 400 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   157.59ms   26.42ms 311.14ms   88.96%
    Req/Sec   636.02    147.04     1.01k    72.50%
  76012 requests in 30.06s, 20.80MB read
  Non-2xx or 3xx responses: 76012
Requests/sec:   2529.01
Transfer/sec:    708.82KB
```

I did dozens of test and the results were close (-+%5)

Comment: *"I thought compiled codes would run faster"* It's compiled either way, `babel-node` just does it Just In Time rather than in advance. The end result should be the same (assuming the same settings are used), just with a brief delay in the `babel-node` case while it does the compilation step. If you're seeing what you're seeing, I'd have to assume that different settings are being used by `babel-node` and `babel-cli`.

Comment: Side note: With an up-to-date version of Node, you don't need Babel to use class properties (`plugin-proposal-class-properties`). Maybe `babel-node` is detecting that and not transpiling them, whereas `babel-cli` is transpiling them.

Comment: I updated my node to 15.11. And my babel-node became slower too.

Comment: If you've removed that proposal plugin, why do you need to use Babel at all? What are you using that Node v15 doesn't support?

Comment: I saw node's ES support just now. I will try it. And sorry i gave wrong information in my last comment. I did not remove class-properties plugin.

Comment: Using node's ES module support solved my speed issue. But I still got no idea why babel-cli was slow.

Comment: My money is on what I said above: `babel.cli` was doing a lot of transpiling to ES5 (or whatever) level code that `babel-node` wasn't doing. You can look at the output of `babel.cli` to see what was being run. I suspect it was doing a **lot** of unnecessarily transpiling.